# AutoMapper creates 'ghost' objects when unflattening 3 level hierarchy

Tags: c#, automapper

We are trying to flatten a nested hierarchy like `Order -may have a-> Customer -has an-> Address` into a model that contains all these entities' models as a root property like this:

```
public class FlatModel
{
    public OrderModel Order { get; set; }
    public CustomerModel Customer { get; set; }
    public AddressModel CustomerAddress { get; set; }
}
```

The flattening works as expected with this mapping profile:

```
public class FlatModelProfile : Profile
{
    public FlatModelProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Order, OrderModel>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Customer, CustomerModel>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Address, AddressModel>().ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<Order, FlatModel>()
            .ForMember(m => m.Order, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p))
            .ForMember(m => m.Customer, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Customer))
            .ForMember(m => m.CustomerAddress, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Customer.Address))
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

However, when we unflatten the `FlatModel` back into an `Order` when the users submits their changes, the `Customer` property will not be null, even though the `Customer` property on the `FlatModel` is.

The following gist shows how to reproduce the issue: https://gist.github.com/luetm/6c4caf62f76e430ad74dd13adf82c451

How to we have to setup the mapping so the `Customer` property on `Order` stays null?

Comment: Avoid `ReverseMap`, just create the maps explicitly.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu We tried, but that's not possible, because this map `.ForMember(o => o, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.Order))` is not legal, and neither is `.ForMember(o => o.Customer.Address, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.CustomerAddress));` apparently... Can you help us with the explicit reverse map, please?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/luetm/65175b7fde4a6bd31bb9ed9c3e25de5c This would be the way to do it right? That's apparently not supported. Do I just have to stitch everything together manually in multiple steps? Also, should `ReverseMap` be avoided always, meaning that I shouldn't use it neither for the simple Entity to Model mappings? What's it's use then? It's very confusing and the docs don't really cover this case. They cover flattening it all together (so all the primitives are on `FlatModel` but not that kind of 'semi-flattening'.